# How to fix "Maximum Call Stack Exceeded" without using a base case for the function that is causing it

Tags: javascript, loops

I am adding a hover event to an element. This event triggers a function which inside contains a loop and it also calls itself again when the loop finishes, because I want the function to be running as long as there is a hover event.

I am getting the following error `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

I know this error means that a function is calling itself without a base case, consequently creating an infinite loop.

I do not want to add a base case because I want the function to keep running as long as there is a hover event.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

```
function arrowAnimation(){

let array = ['0.1', '0.1', '1', '0.6'];
var arrowLoop = function (array) {

    for (let i = 0; i < arrows.length; i++) {

        arrows[i].style.opacity = array[i]; 
        if (i === array.length - 1) { 

            let lastElement = array.pop();
            array = [lastElement].concat(array);
            arrowLoop(array);

          }
       }
    }

     arrowLoop(array);
}

function arrowAnimatiom() {
    t = setInterval(arrowAnimation, 100);
 }

 function stopArrowAnimation() {
     clearInterval(t);
 }


var hover = function (d) {
    arrowAnimatiom();
    var barElementCoords = document.getElementById(d.scaleKeys).getBoundingClientRect();;
    var div = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    div.style.left = barElementCoords.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = barElementCoords.y - 45 + 'px';
    div.innerHTML = d.valuesExplanations;
    div.style.width = d.valuesExplanations.length + 80 + 'px'

};


var hoverOut = function (d) {
    stopArrowAnimation();
    var div = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    div.style.top = -150 + 'px';
    div.style.left = -150 + 'px';
}


 svg_.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(chartData_)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar__")
    .attr("id", function (d) { return d.scaleKeys })
    .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.scaleKeys); })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.scaleValues); })
    .attr("height", function (d) { return height_ - y(d.scaleValues); })
    .style('fill', function (d) { return setBarColor(d.scaleValues) })
    .on("mouseover", hover)
    .on('mouseout', hoverOut)
```

Comment: I think you're confused about event handling. The clue is in this statement: "_keep running as long as there is a hover event._". A _hover event_ is a single thing that, by definition, cannot be in a continuous state. If you think about this in those terms, you don't need a loop at all. Simply allow the event to fire and call the call back on each _individual_ event occurrence. That achieves your goal of execution while hover events continue to fire.

Comment: Also what exactly do you mean by "hover event"? What event is it?

Comment: You could probably do this animation with CSS, then you just assign a class on hover and remove it on unhover.

Comment: thank you all for the answers. I am adding the hover event in a d3 chain process. I have added the rest of the code. I know it is messy so I appreciate any feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => arrowLoop(array));
```

which will clear the call stack and start fresh.